# Create array of Pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This may seem like a very basic request. But my head is too fuzzy to figure out the correct way of doing this.

I have a multi-dimensional array of keywords. These are being split up into columns. I plan on limiting them to only 2 appearing in a column at a time. 5 columns total, each consisting of 2 keywords. This is what consists of a "page".

What I have below is wrong. The inner `for` where I'm attempting to assign a page, is incorrect. The outer `for` does **exactly** what I need (limits the data to just 2 words/column).

```
for (i; i < keywordData.length; i++) {
    nkeywordData[i] = keywordData[i].splice(start,limit);
    for (var k=0; k < nkeywordData.length; k++){
        pages[k] = nkeywordData;
    }
}
```

Sample Data:

```
$rootScope.keywordData = [
    ["column1","test1","test1","tea","party", "water bottle"],
    ["column2","test2","test2","test2 test2"],
    ["column3","test3","t3","longer test3 "],
    ["column4","test4","testing4 tesf asdfsdf"],
    ["column8","test5","test5 asdfsdfasdfasdfasa asda asdfsas"]
];
```

I have other functions in place that handle putting things into columns, etc. Just can't get pages to work.

**Expected outcome**: 3 pages, last page will only have `party, water bottle` in the array, as it is the longest. The other arrays will be empty.

This is what the first "page" would look like. Then as I click "show more" the next "page" would be appended below it.

[image: keygenshowmore]

Comment: Should a page contain just one column or be multi-dimensional?

Comment: Page will be multi-dimensional I assume. At index 0, we'd find the first 2 "rows" of data over 5 columns. I added a screenshot to help with visualizing how things look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you an array `pages` as you described.  Let me know if I missed something.

```
var idxPage;
for (var i=0; i < keywordData.length; i++) {
    column = keywordData[i];
    for(var k=0; k < column.length; k++){
        idxPage = Math.floor(k / limit);
        if (!pages[idxPage]){
            pages[idxPage] = [];   
        }
        if (!pages[idxPage][i]){
            pages[idxPage][i] = [];   
        }
        pages[idxPage][i].push(column[k]); 
    }
}

alert(pages[0][0]);   // ["column1", "test1"]
alert(pages[0][1]);   // ["column2", "test2"]
alert(pages[1][0]);   // ["test1", "tea"]
alert(pages[1][1]);   // ["test2", "test2 test2"] 
alert(pages[2][0]);   // ["party", "water bottle"]
alert(pages[2][1]);   // undefined
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/5fqJe/)

Comment: The logic seems to be off there. Your expected results of `column1, test` actually return `test1, tea`

Comment: Have you checked the fiddle, its exactly as stated here.  I'll add the alerts.

Comment: Ahhh. I realize why it's skipping over the first "row"... Because I was testing it after my original `for` loop, which splices data from `keywordData`. So the problem was self-inflicted (as most of my problems are!)

Comment: I added an HTML output to the fiddle.  Please accept the answer if it works for you :)